# sh: flake8: not found, though I installed it with python pip

Tags: python, docker, pip, flake8

Here I'm going to use flake8 within a docker container. I installed flake8 using the following command and everything installed successfully.

> $ sudo -H pip3 install flake8   // worked fine

and it's location path is-

> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages

Then I executed the following command but result was not expected.

> $ sudo docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "flake8"

It says,

> sh: flake8: not found

May be, the flake8 package is not installed in the correct location path. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Hi @MarcinOrlowski,
how can I add '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages' to PATH?

Comment: I tried with $ sudo docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flake8" ; but same returns -> sh: flake8: not found

Comment: 1) Are you installing flake8 inside the container, or outside the container? 2) You're using `--rm`. This removes changes to the container after each command is executed.

Comment: `sudo pip install` is a bad idea to begin with -- you'd probably do better to use a virtualenv or a local install

Comment: Hi @NickODell, I've installed flake8 with '$ sudo -H pip3 install flake8'

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages` is a directory for *libraries*, it should not be added to PATH; the corresponding `/bin/` directory should.

Comment: That's right but I meant location of the `flake8` binary, whenever OP put it. None the less, I think @David-Maze's answer nails the exact culprit here.

Answer (score 2):

When you `docker-compose run` a container, it is in a new container in a new isolated filesystem.  If you ran `pip install` in a debugging shell in another container, it won't be visible there.

As a general rule, **never install software into a running container**, unless it's for very short-term debugging.  This will get lost as soon as the container exits, and it's very routine to destroy and recreate containers.

If you do need a tool like this, you should install it in your Dockerfile instead:

```bash
FROM python:3.10
...
RUN pip3 install flake8
```

However, for purely developer-oriented tools like linters, it may be better to not install them in Docker at all.  A Docker image contains a fixed copy of your application code and is intended to be totally separate from anything on your host system.  You can do day-to-day development, including unit testing and style checking, in a non-Docker virtual environment, and use `docker-compose up --build` to get a container-based integration-test setup.